# Concept of non-blocking socket functions using WSAWaitforMultipleEvents()

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking, udp

I am using WSAWaitforMultipleEvents() functions and I think that made my sockets non-blocking i.e. recvfrom() is only called only when FD_READ Event is generated and data is available at socket to be read. So, my recvfrom() doesnot block in call.

Is my approach of making the socket non-blocking correct? Because now I am feeling that still my program is blocking waiting for Event so it doesn't really look non-blocking. I am adding a piece of my code for help.

Thanks in advance :)

```
   while(1)
   {
     waitRet = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, &hEvent, FALSE, INFINITE, FALSE);
     if(WSAEnumNetworkEvents(newSocketIdentifier,hEvent,&events) == SOCKET_ERROR)
     {
      "FAILURE"
      continue;
     }
     else
     {   //else event occurred
        if(events.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)
        {
           //FD_READ
          if((recv_len = recvfrom(newSocketIdentifier, receiveBuffer, sizeof(receiveBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientSocket, &clientSocketLength)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
          {
             //error in recvfrom
          }
          else
          {
            //recvfrom() succeeded
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the socket non-blocking in a much simpler way by making its handle non-blocking by using (recvfrom() will not block then):

`ioctlsocket(<socket handle>, FIONBIO, <make it non-zero to enable non-blocking>)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your post. I have little confusions here. Will adding this single line make my socket non blocking? Can I simple call recvfrom() and sendto() inside while(1) and those functions will not block?
`ioctlsocket(<socket handle>, FIONBIO, <make it non-zero to enable non-blocking>)

while(1)
{
recvfrom();
sendto();
}`

in this code will sendto() will be called immediately even if no data is received by recvfrom() or recvfrom() will block to receive data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [WSAWaitForMultipleEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you have already created an event (with [WSACreateEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and connected it to the socket (with [WSAEventSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). From the MSDN documentation:

> The **WSAEventSelect** function automatically sets socket *s* to nonblocking
>   mode, regardless of the value of *lNetworkEvents*.

So, the following code implicitly sets the socket to nonblocking mode:

```
WSAEVENT hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
WSAEventSelect( newSocketIdentifier, hSocketEvent, FD_READ );
```

WSAWaitForMultipleEvents will "block" until it receives an event (or timeouts), but that has nothing to do with blocking/nonblocking mode of sockets.